# Derived variable origin

Tags: education, collegescorecard

I was wondering how the variable `SCH_DEG` from [College Scorecard](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/) was derived. What does it mean to be the degree prominently awarded in terms of the actual #'s? Is it > 50% or more than that?

Answer (score 1):

It's the type of degree that makes up a larger percentage than any other.

From the [documentation](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/FullDataDocumentation.pdf):

> Predominant undergraduate degree (PREDDEG) identifies the type of 
>   degree that the institution primarily awards; for instance, an
>   institution that awards 40 percent bachelor’s degrees, 30 percent
>   associate degrees, and 30 percent certificate programs would be
>   classified as predominantly bachelor’s degree awarding

`SCH_DEG` is `PREDEG` with missing values imputed.